# OSX Catalina FV and Add User Script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, base64, sh

We would like to use a bash script to create a user in the background during the start-up process and add it to FileVault.

Adding the user works.
Adding to FileVault ends with an error message

Error message:

(This is most likely due to the fact that a change has been made since OSX 10.13 where users created via the CLI do not get a secure token and this one for activating filevault)

And we would also like to hide the password in the script as it is a security hole if this is in plain text, would you have an idea here?

Pleas help me

```
USERNAME="backupuser"
FULLNAME="backupuser"
PRIMARYP="USERSPASSWORD"
AUSGABE="administrator"

# ===========================


# Benutzer wird erstellt
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME >> /Users/$AUSGABE/Desktop/ausgabe.txt;

dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UserShell /bin/bash >> /Users/$AUSGABE/Desktop/ausgabe.txt;

# Benutzer erhält den Anzeigenahmen
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME RealName "$FULLNAME" >> /Users/$AUSGABE/Desktop/ausgabe.txt;

# Findet die nächst verfügbare Benutzer ID
MAXID=$(dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | awk '{print $2}' | sort -ug | tail -1)
USERID=$((MAXID+1)) >> /Users/$AUSGABE/Desktop/ausgabe.txt;

# Benutzer erhält Benutzer ID
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UniqueID "$USERID"

# Benutzer wird zu einer Lokalen Gruppe hinzugefügt, 
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME PrimaryGroupID 20

# Benutzerordner wird erstellt
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME NFSHomeDirectory /Local/Users/rescueuser 

# Benutzerpoasswort wird gesetzt
dscl . -passwd /Users/$USERNAME $PRIMARYP 

# Timeout für 5 Sekunden.
sleep 5;

# ===========================

# Benutzer wird zu FileVault hinzugefügt 
#sudo fdesetup add -inputplist < /Users/administrator/Desktop/MacadduserFV.plist

sysadminctl -adminUser "admin" -adminPassword - -secureTokenOn "$USERNAME" -password -

expect -c "
spawn fdesetup add -usertoadd $USERNAME
expect \"Enter the user name:\"
send $USERNAME\r
expect \"Enter the password for user '$USERNAME':\"
send $PRIMARYP\r
expect \"Enter the password for the added user '$USERNAME':\"
send $PRIMARYP\r 
interact"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for an answer - use `sysadminctl` to create the user account and you can use it to add the secure token needed for filevault, but you're going to need to prompt for authentication.

sysadminctl

-addUser  [-fullName ] [-UID ] [-shell ] [-password ] [-hint ] [-home ] [-admin] [-picture ] (interactive] || -adminUser  -adminPassword )

-secureTokenOn  -password  (interactive || -adminUser  -adminPassword )

Comment: If you predict your code with four spaces it gets rendered in code font. Alternatively you can click on the {} button in the editing toolbar.